# ASP.NET - PartialView continues using layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a checkout flow consisting of several steps. For performance reasons I work with ajax partial updates, thus I only want to return partial views without the layout.

Note that I am using ASP.NET Mvc, not ASP.NET Core!

First, I have an index method that loads a view that then will the partial of the step the order currently is in.

```
        public override ActionResult Index(TradeInCheckOutPage currentPage)
    {
        var model = new BaseCheckoutStepViewModel(bulkOrderViewModel, currentPage,
            GetCurrentStep(orderViewModel));
        return View(Index.cshtml", model); // View handles redirect to correct view
    }
```

The view of that method:

```
    if (Model.Step.Equals(CheckoutStep.Confirm))
    {
        Html.RenderAction("confirm", "CheckoutPage",
            new
            {
                currentPageId = Model.CurrentPage.PageId,
            });
    }
    else if (Model.Step.Equals(CheckoutStep.ChooseSenderAddress))
    {
        Html.RenderAction("chooseAddress", "CheckoutPage",
            new
            {
                CurrentPage = Model.CurrentPage.PageId,
                BulkOrderId = Model.BulkOrder.Id
            });
    }
```

The order is in the state 'Confirm', so the method Confirm is called via Html.RenderAction.

```
        public ActionResult Confirm(Guid currentPageId)
    {
        var model = new CheckoutConfirmViewModel(null, GetCurrentPage(currentPageId));

        return View("Confirm.cshtml", model);
    }
```

The view of that method, that initiates an ajax call for a partial:

```
   @{
        Layout = "_LayoutCheckOut.cshtml";
    }
    
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "content"
    }))
    {
    
    }
```

I have the following code in my controller that gets hit by the ajax call:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Confirm(Guid currentPageId, bool confirm = false)
    {          
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return chooseAddress(currentPageId, bulkOrder.Id);
        }

        public PartialViewResult chooseAddress(Guid currentPageId, Guid bulkOrderId)
    {
      ...
        return PartialView("ChooseAddress.cshtml", model);
    }
```

Problem is that for some reason the chooseAddress method viewresult is still using the layout despite it being a PartialViewResult! What's causing this?

I've tried specifying Layout = null in the ChooseAddress view too, but still the layout is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Html.RenderPartial("chooseAddress", "CheckoutPage",...
```

Instead of  `Html.RenderAction("chooseAddress", "CheckoutPage",...`

Also add the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute to your `chooseAddress` Action. Its a good practice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I can't use Html.RenderPartial since I need to call the action "chooseAddress", since it contains logic for building the viewmodel. Depending on which step I am in the checkout flow, a different viewmodel might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue!

Cause was that I had the following lines in _LayoutCheckOut (literally like this, for a quick local set-up), which loaded scripts:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" integrity="sha512-f04GBpoqEZhbyjlRTuXeg8FIHDb+xfCJ0LVdqiN1fEl5B3jz3Z0SPe9IxDumOVdTeeXmKMcMJhb26VuGf1Laqw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" integrity="sha512-Sw6xGAALk16gIMo01Nzur7z1lrF5DLbIy/cd9JiBy4yvcQsXwEnJRMHtTg2/OIO76WGv4C1yR+mCUkOtENKDTA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Apparently when you load in scripts in your view even though it is a partial and you specify layout = null, the layout will still be used!